# Why the following code provides four files(bootstrap.css ,isotope.css ,owl.carousel.css ) to the client browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new in CDATA area,i have faced a problem
So i have to ask if this is most silly question

My code :

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var userSettings = {"url":"\/wordpress\/powerman\/","uid":"0","time":"1499848194","secure":""};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

I can not understand why are slash and backslash symbol mixed in url region or especially what do they mean and why the following code responsible for sending four files to browser?

Comment: the backslash escapes characters inside a string. I'm no Wordpress expert as WordPress is to easy to hack for my time to be spent on it, but go to the url - might have the stylesheets in that url that returns the html data?

Comment: This does not load any files, but sets the value of a variable only. And `/` needs to be escaped simply because the first `/` in the text content of a script element implicitly _closes_ that element.

Comment: But browser show line number 76 is responsible for this problem and this code is located in that line.